# hive query result send to api using curl post

Tags: facebook

I need query a hive table and then send that data to facebook conversion api using curl.
Not able to figure out how to do it through Bash or python.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api

Comment: What part are you not able to figure out?

Comment: How to store hive query output in variable and iterate all rows and do curl -post to facebook api, for example "select * from hive_table limit 10", then iterate this resulltset line by line and curl post it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?